# ImportError: cannot import name 'App' from 'kivy.app'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
 from kivy.uix.label import Label
 from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

 class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text="Edureka!", font_size=150)
        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleApp().run()``




   C:\Users\Miriam\untitled\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Miriam/untitled/Lib/site-packages/kivy/app.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Miriam\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-06-04_4.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Miriam\untitled\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Miriam\untitled\Scripts\python.exe"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Miriam/untitled/Lib/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\Miriam\untitled\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
 ImportError: cannot import name 'App' from 'kivy.app' (C:\Users\Miriam\untitled\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Everytime I try to import App or app from kivy.app, no matter the code I write, I get this error that says that I cannot import app from kivy.app. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !
```

to the top of you file.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried what you told me but it still doesn't work. I looked in that app file from kivy and I found that it s actually empty. It is normal? If you have other suggetion, I would like to try them. Thanks